# How can I avoid the first function call on a webpage taking so long?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application

I've developed a single page web-app that has several thousand lines of **JavaScript** code. 
The first time a user clicks a button, there is a long delay (about 1.5 seconds) before the action takes place. After that, clicking a button produces immediate results.

What is happening? I'm thinking that it is scans through all the

`<script>`

tags on the page on that first click...

I tried to add a last line of code to run on read `$(handler) [jquery]`, that just calls a function that logs "ready" in the console. But it did not work.

How can I avoid this initial lag?

Comment: What happens if you just sit there for a few seconds without hitting any buttons, and only then hit a button? Is there still a delay?

Comment: Can we see the code ?

Comment: is the call behind the button is AJAX request?

Comment: Also learn how to use http://requirejs.org/ It will help you if you need handle a lot of javascript code

Comment: With Chrome browser, using F12, you can see what part of your code takes so long. Click the tab `Profiles` and press the `start` button. Click your button that create the delay and stop the profile recording.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the Javascript files as you need them -- grab some when a tab is clicked, when something is loaded, etc.  It's difficult to tell without any code, but you need to break it up (not load it all at once).

Answer (score 0):

***Javascript*** is, in fact, compiled and pre-compiled.

In fact, the nature of ***V8 JavaScript VM*** used in ***Chrome*** is a two thread process of "compile as needed" and re-optimize / re-factor as you go along.

Put simply, a ***JavaScript*** App should become more efficient as you use it.

Still, your experience begs the question of whether your code could be optimized. If you are using ***Raw JS*** without any libraries, you are probably running afoul of many best practices that ***JS*** experts have learned through pain and error.

- If possible, I'd lookin into how complex are your functions?
- can you refactor with JQuery
- do you define many variable on fly (on assignment) or before us (more efficient).

I stop here, because the questions could go on forever, and you say you have thousands of lines of code. The best course is to analyze this particular call back and functions associated for best practices.